# How to get django-admin.py command working in windows 7

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have installed django 1.6.4 on my windows 7 (32-bit) machine, I'm using python 2.7.6

But when i started to create my project by using following command:

```
C:\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

it doesn't create any folder named mysite under my current directory, instead it just simply runs the django-admin.py script, in fact no matter what i type after django-admin.py command i get the output of django-admin.py script on the command prompt.

```
C:\django-admin.py startproject mysite
C:\django-admin.py abcdefghi
```

both of the above commands just simply runs the django-admin.py script and does nothing else.

I checked online but i couldn't seem to find out the actual problem.

I have set all the environment variables of python and of django

Path= C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/1.6/django-admin/) :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/1.6/django-admin/

> For Windows users, who do not have symlinking functionality available,
>   you can copy django-admin.py to a location on your existing path or
>   edit the PATH settings (under Settings - Control Panel - System -
>   Advanced - Environment...) to point to its installed location.